# What Do Multiple Return Statements in a Linq.Select() Do?

Tags: c#, linq, select

I'm seeing a lot of select statements with return statements in them and Im confused of what is going on when an object is being returned from within a select statement. Can someone please explain?

```
var results = swimEntries
    .Select(se =>
{
      if (se.Tag == "DM+" || se.Tag == "DM-")
      {
         var modelEntry =
             modelEntries.Find(e => e.Tag == se.Tag);


         return modelEntry;
      }

   return se;
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: A "select statement" is simply a loop over the input collection, calling a method on each element, and then returning a collection of the objects returned from those methods. In other words, you're passing in element objects to the method here, and you either get out the original element (`return se;`), or a `modelEntry`.

Comment: [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is a Statement lambda. The `Select()` will call for each item the code in it's body. When the `se.Tag` meets some criteria, it will search for an object in the modelEntries.

You could write this statement also as:

```
var results = new List<ModelEntry>();  // <-- i don't know the exact type.. (wild guess)

foreach(var se in swimEntries)
{
    if (se.Tag == "DM+" || se.Tag == "DM-")
    {
        var modelEntry = modelEntries.Find(e => e.Tag == se.Tag);
        results.Add(modelEntry);
    }
    else
        results.Add(se);
}
```

or if you want to keep the Select statement, you could store the body into a separate function:

```
private ModelEntry SearchForSomething(ModelEntry se)
{
    if (se.Tag == "DM+" || se.Tag == "DM-")
    {
        var modelEntry = modelEntries.Find(e => e.Tag == se.Tag);

        return modelEntry;
    }
    return se;
}


var results = swimEntries.Select(SearchForSomething).ToList();
```

Comment: If anyone is confused by the syntax of `var results = swimEntries.Select(SearchForSomething).ToList();`, this is called "Method Groups".  The more traditional syntax would look like `var results = swimEntries.Select(e => SearchForSomething(e)).ToList();`.  These are functionally equivalent.

Comment: _"Traditional"_..... The `Select` method accepts a `Func<>` which is a delegate. So the _traditional_ way would be passing a method. But nowadays we are more inclined to write lambda's. Nevertheless, good addition!